# How to pass InputStream to REST service POST method

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs, postman

How to pass `InputStream` to `createParcel()` method using Java REST client? How to call `POST` request using POSTMAN?

```java
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public int createParcel(InputStream is) {
    int awbNo = 0;
    try {
        ParcelInfo parcelInfo = null;
        parcelInfo = buildParcelInfo(is);
        awbNo = index.incrementAndGet();
        parcelInfo.setAwbNo(awbNo);
        parcelInfo.setStatus("new");
        parcelDataMap.put(awbNo, parcelInfo);
   } catch(Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Getting some exception for creating parcel : "+ex.getMessage(), ex);
   }
   return awbNo;
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public StreamingOutput getParcelInfo(@QueryParam("awbNo") int awbNo) {
    ParcelInfo parcelInfo = null;
    String xml = null;
    parcelInfo = parcelDataMap.get(awbNo);

    if (parcelInfo != null) {
        xml = convert(parcelInfo);
    }
    return new ParcelInfoWriter(xml);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you are not consuming structured data but rather a raw InputStream, you first remove the `@Consumes` annotation; so your resource method should be:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public int createParcel(InputStream is) {
    int awbNo = 0;
    try {
        ParcelInfo parcelInfo = null;
        parcelInfo = buildParcelInfo(is);
        // the rest of your code here
   }catch(Exception ex) {
        // catch specific exception instead of `Exception`
   }
   return awbNo;
}
```

Now use Postman to call your resource. The content body of your request can be any conent (in my example it is XML but you can send anything you like). Look at the screenshot below how to set the request correctly:

[image]

Execuse me for the drawing :-)